# Update panel with textbox values when button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, panel

I am still learning the basics of C# so any help would be appreciated.  I have a series of `asp:TextBox`'s.  In the code behind, I am getting the value of these boxes.  Is there a way to have a panel hidden until a user clicks submit then have the values display?

Here is the HTML for one of the boxes and the panel:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Panel ID="PDFPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

The button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSubmit"/>
```

and the code-behind for it:

```
string Title = txtTitle.Text;

 public void btnSubmit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

There are about 50 fields, so I am not showing all of it but if I can get direction on one I can replicate for the rest.  Please let me know if I need to show any additional code

I am sorry if this is simple, but like I said, I am still an entry level developer.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood what you're asking, this should be fairly simple.

```
<asp:Panel ID="PDFPanel" runat="server" Visible="False">
   <div>
       <asp:Literal id="litTitle" runat="server" />
   </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

then in your click method:

```
litTitle.Text = txtTitle.Text;
PDFPanel.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Nope, you understand correctly.  This is a simple task that I was confused on how to properly syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `Panel`'s visibility to false by default

```
<asp:Panel ID="PDFPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

then on the `Button`'s click event set the visibility to true

```
public void btnSubmit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PDFPanel.Visible = true;
    // do something else...
}
```